# Is there an alternative way to dynamically create this array of double values?

Tags: vba, autocad, autocad-plugin

I am developing a VBA macro to use in **AutoCAD**. At the moment it converts a **circle** into a **3D polyline** and in itself it is working perfectly. It is just the start and I will be able to put some flesh on the final routine.

This is the VBA macro:

```
 Sub CircleToPolyline()
    Dim objSel As AcadEntity
    Dim myCircle As AcadCircle
    Dim pickedPoint As Variant

    ' Get the user to select a circle
    ' Eventually we will use a Selection Set with Filtering to pick them all in the drawing
    Call ThisDrawing.Utility.GetEntity(objSel, pickedPoint, "Select Circle:")
    If objSel.ObjectName <> "AcDbCircle" Then GoTo SKIP

    Set myCircle = objSel
    Dim dAngle As Double, dAngleStep As Double, dMaxAngle As Double

    dAngle = 0# ' We always start at 0 degrees / radians
    dAngleStep = 0.17453293 ' This is 10 degrees in radians
    dMaxAngle = 6.28318531 ' This is 360 degrees in radians
    ' So our polyline will always have 36 vertices

    Dim ptCoord() As Double
    Dim ptProject As Variant
    Dim i As Integer

    i = 0
    While dAngle < dMaxAngle
        ReDim Preserve ptCoord(0 To i + 2) ' Increase size of array to hold next vertex

        ' Calculate the next coordinate on the edge of the circle
        ptProject = ThisDrawing.Utility.PolarPoint(myCircle.center, dAngle, myCircle.Radius)

        ' Add to the coordinate list
        ptCoord(i) = ptProject(0)
        ptCoord(i + 1) = ptProject(1)
        ptCoord(i + 2) = ptProject(2)

        ' Increment for next coordinate/angle on the circle edge
        dAngle = dAngle + dAngleStep
        i = i + 3
    Wend

    ' Create the 3D polyline
    Dim oPolyline As Acad3DPolyline
    Set oPolyline = ThisDrawing.ModelSpace.Add3DPoly(ptCoord)
    oPolyline.Closed = True
    oPolyline.Update

SKIP:

 End Sub
```

I am just wondering if there are any alternative methods for managing my dynamic array (`ptCoord`)? For example, is there any way that I can just add the `ptProject` into a dynamic list and then just use this list in the **Add3dPoly** routine?

The thing is, **PolarPoint** returns a **variant**. And **ptCoord** is a array of **doubles** (which is what **Add3dPoly** expects). This is why I have done it like this. I have not used variants (except for handling *return values*).

My code is quite simple and sufficient, but if it can be further simplified I would be interested in knowing (given the context of VBA and AutoCAD environment).

I hope my question is clear. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is feasible to allocate a chunk of memory and write the sequential results of each of your `PolarPoint` calls to it. You could then copy that memory to your `ptCoord` array in one call. However, the APIs are very awkward, there'd be a lot of fiddling with pointers (never straightforward in VBA) and most memory coding errors result in a complete Excel crash. For 108 data points it doesn't seem worth the effort.

I'd say your notion of iterating each of the result arrays and writing them individually to `ptCoord` is as good a way as any.

Your comments

> 'We always start at 0 degrees / radians, and 'So our polyline will always have 36 vertices

suggest your `ptCoord` array will have a fixed dimension (ie 36 * 3). If that's the case couldn't you just dimension the array once? Even if you want to vary the number of degrees to draw through, you could still dimension your array at (n * 3) without having to `ReDim Preserve` on every iteration.

A snippet of your code could therefore become:

```
Dim alpha As Double
Dim index As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim ptCoord(0 To 107) As Double
Dim ptProject() As Double
Dim pt As Variant
...
For i = 0 To 35
    ptProject = ThisDrawing.Utility.PolarPoint(myCircle.center, dAngle, myCircle.Radius)
    For Each pt In ptProject
        ptCoord(index) = pt
        index = index + 1
    Next
    alpha = alpha + 0.174532925199433
Next
```

Comment: Valid point about the fixed array size. However, in your example you use `ptCoord(index) = pt`. But I need 3 indexes for each coordinate. First for x, second for y and third for z. **PolarPoint** returns a variant. Can you explain for me why your code would work? Thanks.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle, I think this code is doing what you're saying. `pt` iterates the returned array. So on each call of the `PolarPoint` function, `pt` would be x, y then z with the index incrementing by 1 on each value.

Comment: OK, I will have to try. But I think `index = index + 1` needs to be `index = index + 3`.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle, I'm not so sure. A `Variant` returned by a function can be pretty much anything (including an array). I'm not familiar with autocad but from your initial code, it looks as though you're expecting it to return an array with 3 values. The line `For Each pt In ptProject` will iterate over those values one at a time and increased `index` by 1 each time. So for every iteration of your angle (ie `i`) `index` will increment by 3. Have a play and see how you go.

Answer (score 1):

Your code appears good to me, I was going to suggest a two dimensional array: -

```
Dim ptCoord(2,0)
...
ptCoord(0,0) = ptProject(0)
ptCoord(1,0) = ptProject(1)
ptCoord(2,0) = ptProject(2)

ReDim Preserve ptCoord(2,1)
ptCoord(0,1) = ptProject(0)
ptCoord(1,1) = ptProject(1)
ptCoord(2,1) = ptProject(2)
```

The second dimension in a two dimensional array can be dynamically re-dimensioned. But I'm not sure this will save you anything and it may not work with `Add3DPoly`.

You could use `UBound` to save on the `i` variable.

```
ReDim Preserve ptCoord(UBound(ptCoord,1)+3)
```

In the above I haven't declared the lower/base (`0 To`) as 0 is the default base, I have then used `UBound` (Upper bound) to get the size of the array and added 3 to that to make it 3 larger.

UBound(*[Array]*,*[Dimension]*)

*Array* being the array you want to check

*Dimension* being the dimension you want to check the size on, it has a base of 1 not 0 (so the first dimension is 1 not 0, the second is 2 not 1, and so on...)

You can omit *Dimension* and the first will be assumed.

To access it without `i` you could use: -

```
ptCoord(UBound(ptCoord,1)-2) = ptProject(0)
ptCoord(UBound(ptCoord,1)-1) = ptProject(1)
ptCoord(UBound(ptCoord,1)) = ptProject(2)
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments. `Add3dPoly` requires a single dimension list `(x,y,z,x,y,z,x,y,z)`. So I don't think I can do this. But I note your comment about using `UBound`. So is it not possible to just add a variant to an array of variants and then easily convert it into a list of double values or is that over complicating it?

Comment: @AndrewTruckle There is a `split` function that may do something close to what you want but it would mean an extra loop, I suspect you are on the best path.

Answer (score 1):

you can skip arrays dimming altogether by use of `AppendVertex()` method

```
Option Explicit

Sub CircleToPolyline()

    Dim myCircle As AcadCircle
    Dim circleCenter As Variant, circleRadius As Double
    Dim dAngle As Double, dAngleStep As Double, dMaxAngle As Double
    Dim oPolyline As Acad3DPolyline

    'Get the user to select a circle
    Set myCircle = GetCircle(circleCenter, circleRadius)
    If myCircle Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    dAngle = 0# ' We always start at 0 degrees / radians
    dAngleStep = 0.17453293 ' This is 10 degrees in radians
    dMaxAngle = 6.28318531 ' This is 360 degrees in radians

    Set oPolyline = GetStarting3dPoly(circleCenter, circleRadius, dAngle, dAngleStep) ' Create the 3D polyline with first two points
    Do While dAngle + dAngleStep <= dMaxAngle
        dAngle = dAngle + dAngleStep ' Increment for next coordinate/angle on the circle edge
        oPolyline.AppendVertex ThisDrawing.Utility.PolarPoint(circleCenter, dAngle, circleRadius) 'append a new vertex
    Loop

    'finish the polyline
    oPolyline.Closed = True
    oPolyline.Update

End Sub


Function GetStarting3dPoly(circleCenter As Variant, circleRadius As Double, dAngle As Double, dAngleStep As Double) As Acad3DPolyline
    Dim ptCoord(0 To 5) As Double
    Dim ptCoords As Variant

    ptCoords = ThisDrawing.Utility.PolarPoint(circleCenter, dAngle, circleRadius)
    ptCoord(0) = ptCoords(0)
    ptCoord(1) = ptCoords(1)
    ptCoord(2) = ptCoords(2)

    dAngle = dAngle + dAngleStep
    ptCoords = ThisDrawing.Utility.PolarPoint(circleCenter, dAngle, circleRadius)
    ptCoord(3) = ptCoords(0)
    ptCoord(4) = ptCoords(1)
    ptCoord(5) = ptCoords(2)

    Set GetStarting3dPoly = ThisDrawing.ModelSpace.Add3DPoly(ptCoord)
End Function


Function GetCircle(circleCenter As Variant, circleRadius As Double) As AcadCircle
    Dim objSel As AcadEntity
    Dim pickedPoint As Variant

    ' Get the user to select a circle
    ' Eventually we will use a Selection Set with Filtering to pick them all in the drawing
    ThisDrawing.Utility.GetEntity objSel, pickedPoint, "Select Circle:"
    If objSel.ObjectName = "AcDbCircle" Then
        Set GetCircle = objSel
        circleCenter = objSel.Center
        circleRadius = objSel.Radius
    End If
End Function
```

as you see I also extracted some actions from the main code and confined them into functions, so to improve further enhancing of your code and its functionalities

Comment: Now that is interesting! Create a single segment polyline first and then just add vertices to the object directly. I like it. :) Only thing is, I already accepted one answer and the original poster would lose the points I awarded them.

Comment: That said, since you are doing the first increment when creating the polyline object `dAngle` should not begin with 0.0 now.  It should begin with `dAngleStep`.

Comment: well your question was about _"any alternative methods for managing my dynamic array"_ and I'd say that both mine and @Ambie 's solutions are alternative. Maybe mine is _more_ alternative but that was not the point, so as long as _both_ answers _are_ working then Ambie's one came in first and would therefore deserve credit. As for the increment issue: did you actually test my solution? (actually: did you test both?...)

Comment: Thank you. I have tested it and it is great. I made some modifications for it to work with my selection set as opposed to a specific circle. But it works very well. Thanks again. :)